# Error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

I have the value 1028 in the file build_ver.txt ,getting the below error while running the following script,script is trying to increment the count by 1 and write the value back to the file..please suggest how to overcome this?

```
with open(r'\\Network\Build_ver\build_ver.txt','w+') as f:
    value = int(f.read())
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(str(value + 1))
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_ver.py", line 2, in <module>
    value = int(f.read())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: I believe you should strip the string before the conversion to int as `f.read().strip()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what opening a file in `w+` mode does:

> **w+**
>   Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does
>   not exist, **otherwise it is truncated**.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

Emphasis mine.  Your file is empty, `read()` will give you an empty string.

Perhaps you want to open in `r+` mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) to modify the file "in-place":

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('\\Network\Build_ver\build_ver.txt', inplace=True):
    print str(int(line) + 1)
```

Everything printed inside the loop is written back to the file.